# Routing Error undefined method `default_locale=' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I got this `Routing Error
undefined method default_locale= for nil:NilClass` issue when I try to logout current user after add rollincode/rails_admin_theme at my rails project.

Does anybody knows how to solve this issue?

Comment: The error message is telling you that the receiver of the method, `default locale=` is nil. Could you share some code snippets showing where you might have used `default locale=` to provide more context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`default_locale` indicates that the `i18n` gem is missing. Add it to your Gemfile.

Comment: Thanks! Actually re-checking my code I've just found a mistake: I had added  `config.i18n.default_locale` at `application.rb` and somehow after I delete that line it works.

Comment: you're welcome. don't forget to accept my answer.